# Can I roast s'mores using static electricity built up by sailing through a nebula and forks/aluminim?

Tags: space, spaceships, electricity

Keep in mind the ship is sailing through a nebula, it's creating static electricity from the dust and debris (I believe this is possible correct me if not).

The [s'mores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%27more) are wrapped in aluminum, there's a pole made of forks that connects to a split panel on the hull of the ship that's letting in small amounts of the static electricity. The forks make a sort of bridge between the split panel and the aluminum wrapped s'mores.

Is it possible to cook the s'mores this way? Yes I know that the hole in the hull is a problem but it's not a serious book. Just one for a good laugh and fun.

Comment: While nebulas are more dense than empty space, the majority are still less dense than any vacuum humanity has ever created on Earth. That they look so striking in space images is because we're generally looking at many light-years of nebula depth with instruments far more sensitive than human eyesight.

Comment: Static electricity is [traditionally considered a hazard for space exploration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_electricity#In_space_exploration).  You'd need a relatively large amount of charge which, if discharged all at once, has the potential to start a fire (not a good thing on a space ship).  Is there a reason you want to get smores this way?  As opposed to just sticking them on whatever is powering your ship.

Answer (score 4):

Static electricity is, by definition, static. Static charges are useful to create electric fields and harass physics and engineering students with questions about those fields, but that aside there are no other physical effects which could result in anything useful to cook something.

If you want to have any thermal effect you need to have moving charges. Since your ship is moving through the nebula, the kinetic energy resulting from the impacts with the space medium seems to be the obvious solution. Instead of having a conventional shield, you can have a layer of s'more taking the impact and being cooked. This would imply that the crew has to keep eating s'mores in order to ensure the ship integrity through the travel by constantly renewing the shield.

Comment: Wouldn't the static charge sometimes be discharged, like lightning?

Comment: @Trioxidane, I think that in a place crammed with free charges like space, you are not going to build potentials large enough to trigger a discharge. As soon as you build a net charge, you will be attracting opposite charges and repelling similar ones from within the flow investing you.